# Resque job is processed but not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, resque, rails-activejob

I'm trying to run a job in the background using resque and after following the docs and a couple of tutorials I am stuck. Running the resque.log it says the job ran but it really didn't.

I am currently calling the job like

```
Resque.enqueue(CsvImporterJob, params[:file].path, @organization.id)
```

This is the job:

```
class CsvImporterJob < ActiveJob::Base
  @queue = :import

  def self.perform(file, organization_id)
    CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
      if row
        user = row.to_hash
        email = user["email"]
        case user["role"].downcase
        when "admin"
          role_id = Role.admin
        else
          role_id = Role.user
        end
        ActivateHelper.send_activation_token(email, organization_id, role_id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the log:

```
D, [2016-04-06T11:02:59.854604 #6548] DEBUG -- : resque-1.25.2: Waiting for *
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.856115 #6548] DEBUG -- : Checking import
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.856388 #6548] DEBUG -- : Found job on import
I, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.856441 #6548]  INFO -- : got: (Job{import} | CsvImporterJob | ["/var/folders/92/87zkvh_53mb3721x4025vmsr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20160406-6422-1t7akw1.csv", 6])
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.856771 #6548] DEBUG -- : resque-1.25.2: Processing import since 1459954984 [CsvImporterJob]
I, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.856811 #6548]  INFO -- : Running before_fork hooks with [(Job{import} | CsvImporterJob | ["/var/folders/92/87zkvh_53mb3721x4025vmsr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20160406-6422-1t7akw1.csv", 6])]
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.858903 #6548] DEBUG -- : resque-1.25.2: Forked 6608 at 1459954984
I, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.859985 #6608]  INFO -- : Running after_fork hooks with [(Job{import} | CsvImporterJob | ["/var/folders/92/87zkvh_53mb3721x4025vmsr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20160406-6422-1t7akw1.csv", 6])]
I, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.865640 #6608]  INFO -- : done: (Job{import} | CsvImporterJob | ["/var/folders/92/87zkvh_53mb3721x4025vmsr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20160406-6422-1t7akw1.csv", 6])
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.869546 #6548] DEBUG -- : Checking import
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.869914 #6548] DEBUG -- : Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:04.869947 #6548] DEBUG -- : resque-1.25.2: Waiting for *
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:09.871048 #6548] DEBUG -- : Checking import
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:09.871237 #6548] DEBUG -- : Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:09.871459 #6548] DEBUG -- : resque-1.25.2: Waiting for *
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:14.872187 #6548] DEBUG -- : Checking import
D, [2016-04-06T11:03:14.872390 #6548] DEBUG -- : Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
```

Anything specific I should be doing? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by setting up the connection with redis correctly

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'

  Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379' unless Rails.env == 'production'

  Resque.before_fork = Proc.new do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end
  Resque.after_fork = Proc.new do |job|
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```